# Query to get friends list from same table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table named **users** with following fields

```
userid, username,email, friends
```

Friends are comma separated values for e.g. 2,3 I want to find friends of a particular user what would be SQL query for it ?

For example user 2 has friends 3,4 the query should return 3 and 4

Comment: Storing comma seperated values of foreign id's is a bad database design

Comment: I agree with @Jens.  Take a look at this fiddle, it breaks the data into two tables.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3592f/1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the

> find_in_set

Example

```
SELECT f.userid FROM users u,users f
WHERE u.userid= 2 AND FIND_IN_SET(f.userid, u.friends)
```